# Optional ifPresent to call an object method

Tags: java, lambda, option-type, sonarlint

I have to call a procedure with the following signature:

```
private Optional<Address> getAddress()
```

And I use it to fill a client's record on my system. So, I made the following code to set the address of the record (if it exists).

```
Optional<Address> address = getAddress();
if (address.isPresent())
  record.setAddress(address.get());
```

However, I get the following notification:

> Can be replaced by ifPresent
>
> Reports conditions like if `Optional.isPresent()` which could be rewritten in functional style.

So I thought *great, I'm going to use this cool `ifPresent` stuff to simplify my code*. Then I came up with this line:

```
getAddress().ifPresent(x -> record.setAddress(x));
```

and thought *nice, 3 lines into one*. But then I got the following message from **SonarLint**

> Replace this lambda with a method reference

and I thought *why should I need to create a method just to set a single variable?*

Anyway, since I'm kind of new to the use of `Optional`, I might be misunderstanding something here... So, how should I make this simple piece of code, according to the recommendations and best practices?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You shouldn't create a new method just to set a single variable. SonarLint just recommends that it is better to use method reference instead of a lambda expression.

You could read about method references in Java 8 at Oracle's website: [The Java Tutorials - Method References](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html).

For your case - SonarLint just wants you to replace that line with this:

```
Record record = ...;
getAddress().ifPresent(record::setAddress);
```

Comment: If I put the Record class, I get `Non static method cannot be referenced from a static context`, but if I do `getAddress().ifPresent(record::setAddress);` (record being the object) It compiles. Is it ok?

Comment: use the variable name instead of `Record`, which in your example is `record`

Comment: correct, the record should be used instead of Record. Thanks, @lucasvw